# How to improve the low-light image quality of my Canon 350d?

Tags: portrait, low-light

I have a Canon 350d. How do I improve the quality of images in low light? I feel like urgrading the body — but will it really help? I have a Canon 18-55 kit lens, 75-300, and a 50mm 1.8. lens. I have a 430 EXii Canon speedlite as well.

Comment: At the moment, this is probably too broad for us to give a helpful answer. Could you post some images you feel are a problem and explain precisely *what* you'd like to improve about them?

Comment: How do I attach a pic here

Comment: Edit the question and use the "attach image" button.

Comment: You've tagged this question with [tag:portrait]. Is that your main area of concern? Do you mean formal portraits, casual snapshots of people, or both (or something different)? In addition to adding an example, it would be helpful if you can be specific about the aspects you are not happy with, if possible.

Comment: It should be clear that the by now ten year old Canon 350d is not going to compete well with even mediocre cameras you can buy today for $400. ISO limited to 1600, bad high ISO performance, no sensor shift, 8MP sensor, dynamic range of less than 11 EV.

Comment: @CountIblis But little of that should matter if the ISO is set to 100 (or as high as 400) and the flash used optimally.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what you've already tried, I'll give some suggestions which might help (although the're not specific to the 350d).

1. Use a fast lens with the f-stop wide open (f/1.8 for example)  - your 50mm lens should be ideal.
2. Use flash if possible.
3. Shoot in RAW mode with the highest quality setting.
4. Use a tool like adobe lightroom for post-processing.

I had a 350d before upgrading to a 500d. The 500d supports higher ISO and has slightly better noise reduction with high ISO.

Comment: Do quality settings matter when shooting RAW with this camera? (I really don't know.)

Comment: Very good question. I believe the answer is no, it doesn't matter. The quality settings are for the JPEG. So if you take a great shot and the JPEG is fine, there's no need to post-processing with the RAW image.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [dXomark](http://www.dxomark.com/Cameras/Compare/Side-by-side/Canon-EOS-600D-versus-Canon-EOS-60D-versus-Canon-EOS-350D___692_663_183) to see how much better low-light exposure you can expect. The numbers should compare within a brand and technology, even if they somehow don't tell the whole story.